# I cant install skype, wine or play on linux

Tags: certificates

Can anybody help? I have been installing software and enjoying ubuntu for several months now,but currently have a problem. If I try to install some programs, such as wine, skype and playon linux as well as some others, I get error messages. the install goes well until the final phase of registering certs and then it fails and the programs don't work. Synaptice hasn't helped much as it is where I get the error messages from while it is trying to install programs. Errors look like this:

```
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
ln: accessing ‘/etc/ssl/certs/Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority.pem’: Input/output error
```

really don't want to do a reinstall. Surely this can be fixed without that. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. I renamed the file to a .org at the end to keep the same name. then I reinstalled the ca-certificates package.

All looks good for now.